# I can't format the usb flash memory stick

Tags: usb-drive, format

Hello guys I have a big problem here!! I tried everything and I can't format this usb. Please help me!

I try to format with `gparted` and disks and with `gparted` I receive those errors:

```
Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sdb has been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes.
udisks-error-quark, 11
ignore this error
```

Also the weird thing is, that the usb flash is 64 GB and `gparted` says 230 GB

[image: there is not format option on disks]

Comment: As it says, ignore that error. It says that it has been formatted, it has just not been able to inform the Linux kernel of the change.

Answer (score 1):

Your device /dev/sdc1 is a Read-only, unmount the disk on Gparted and format.

[Gparted-Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctrQR.png)